# C++ "deque iterator incompatible" error

Tags: c++, multithreading, iterator, queue, deque

I've been implementing a program using socket programming,
and I'm encountering an error message "deque iterator incompatible".

The program code is as follows:
1.

```
while (1)
{
    tmp_fds = read_fds;

    printf("[Waiting Select Signal] \n");
    if (select(maxfd + 1, &tmp_fds, 0, 0, (struct timeval *)0)<1)
    {
        perror("select error : ");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (fd = 0; fd<maxfd + 1; fd++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &tmp_fds))
        {
            if (fd == ssock)
            {
                if ((csock = accept(ssock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clen))<0)
                {
                    perror("accept error : ");
                    exit(0);
                }

                FD_SET(csock, &read_fds);

                printf(" - New client is connected = %d \n", csock);
                stEpInfo[iEpCount].iFDNum = csock;
                stEpInfo[iEpCount].sIpAddr = inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);
                iEpCount++;

                if (csock>maxfd)
                {
                    maxfd = csock;
                }
            }   else
            {
                printf(" - Received Client Socket Signal (FD = %d) \n", fd);
                memset(&read_message, 0, sizeof(read_message));

                data_len = recv(fd, (char*)&read_message, sizeof(read_message), 0);



                CDataQueue::getDataQueue()->pushDataToQueue(read_message);
```

In this source code, the server receives data and throws it in queue, and this happens again and again whenever the server receives data.

2. A thread is working to find out whether the data is inserted to queue or not. If the data are inserted (it means, queue is not empty), the data is going to be popped.

   unsigned WINAPI PreprocessInsert(void *data){

   ```
   printf("[Thread Start] \n");
   CDatabase *l_db = (CDatabase *)data;

   int cnt = 0;
   int iECount = 0;
   ST_CCT stCCT;
   while (1){

       if (!CDataQueue::getDataQueue()->getQueue().empty()){ ST_MONITORING_RESULT poppedData = CDataQueue::getDataQueue()->popDataFromQueue();}
   ```
3. I wrote the code related to queue like this.

   void CDataQueue::pushDataToQueue(ST_MONITORING_RESULT data){

   ```
   ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_stCriticalSection);
   m_deQueue.push_back(data);
   ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_stCriticalSection);
   ```

   }

   ST_MONITORING_RESULT CDataQueue::popDataFromQueue(){

   ```
   ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_stCriticalSection);
   ST_MONITORING_RESULT data = m_deQueue.front();
   m_deQueue.pop_front();
   ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_stCriticalSection);

   return data;
   ```

   }

When the program is run, sometimes "deque iterator incompatible" message is popped up, and sometimes not. When I performed debugging on the program, I saw the received data was in queue, but `if (!CDataQueue::getDataQueue()->getQueue().empty())` statement did not work.

I don't understand what's going on. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're showing far too much code that's NOT about your `deque` and far too little code about the `deque` itself. For instance, where's `getQueue` and how do you manage to return a queue properly guarded by its critical section?

Comment: You might have some undefined behaviour cause by data races. For example, your `CDataQueue::getDataQueue()->getQueue().empty()` is not done under critical section - why ? Also make sure you are not returning somewhere your deque by value, getQueue() should return reference.